# Allowing switching between operator[] and at() based on NDEBUG macro version

Tags: c++, collections, macros

**The problem:**

`std::vector` and other containers have two functions for accessing / modifying their content: `operator[]` and `at()`.

[`at()` is meant for debugging, to catch out-of-bound bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9376094/4385532). However, [`at()` is also quite a lot slower than `operator[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3269809/4385532). Both above facts would yearn for a way to switch between the use of `at()` and `operator[]` based on whether it is a debug build or a production build, especially if performance matters.

However, I can see no such easy way. Sadly standard containers don’t offer a flag or sth that would allow to do this.

I tried to write a simple wrapper that would switch between `at()` and `operator[]` based on whether or not `NDEBUG` is defined, in line with how the `assert` macro works.

**Note:** This is a different solution to the same problem as stated here: [Allowing switching between operator[] and at() based on NDEBUG](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/158078/78399) This solves the issue of 2d arrays. But I wanted to post two solutions, 'cuz I feared You could frown upon such a macro :(

**The code:**

```
// AOO = At Or Operator[]
#ifndef NDEBUG
  #define AOO(INDEX) .at(INDEX)
#else
  #define AOO(INDEX) [INDEX]
#endif
```

**The use:**

```
void testNormalUse()
{
    std::vector<int> vec(100);
    vec AOO(50) = 5;
    std::cout << vec AOO(50) << std::endl;
}

void testRequireConst()
{
    const std::vector<int> vec(100, 5);
    std::cout << vec AOO(50) << std::endl;
}

void testRvalueRef()
{
    std::vector<int>vec(100, 5);
    std::cout << std::move(vec) AOO(50) << std::endl;
}

void test2d()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(100, std::vector<int>(100, 5));
    std::cout << vec AOO(50) AOO(50) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    testNormalUse();
    testRequireConst();
    testRvalueRef();
    test2d();
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/8QPfIx)

Of course I know this is weird syntax. But the non-macro solution brings up pain with multidimensional arrays, a problem the macro version solves.

If only macros allowed punctuation, then we could make it look operator-like. But alas, they don't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowing switching between \`operator\[\]\` and \`at()\` based on \`NDEBUG\`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158078/allowing-switching-between-operator-and-at-based-on-ndebug)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is it forbidden on this site to post two substantially different solutions to same problem?

Comment: Forbidden? No. But it's considered good practice to declare what you did and why to help the reviewers understand why you did what you did. The usual approach though, is posting both pieces of code in the same question and tag as [tag:comparative-review].